# Suggestion for using profile with user inputs

Tags: meteor

Using Meteor, I like to get suggestion to use profiles with input variables defined in it.

When using it, I wanted to prompt all the input variables in the profile.

Finally I wanted to replace input variables with the customer inputs and generate a config file.

Same profile:

Section A:

City Name                     {{CityName}}
Name                          {{Name}}

Section B:

Device Ip                    {{deviceIP}}
Device Name                  {{deviceName}}

With User inputs, I wanted to generate the config file:

Section A:

City Name                     Dallas
Name                          Chris

Section B:

Device Ip                    99.99.12.111
Device Name                  DAL_1

Comment: config for displaying? Template helpers can be written in JS.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  I wanted to generate the config file with the input from the user. Wanted to predefine input variable. Using these input,I wanted to generate the config file with predefined configs.